# enabling cors on a nginx server in ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im deploying my Nodejs app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk running nginx.

The app is essentially an api, which i can make calls to and retrieve back JSON data i.e. myapi.awselasticbeanstalk.com/api/get_stuff etc.

Im trying to enable CORS so i can access the server from my javascript application (the client).

As per amazon documentation I can edit or extend the nginx configuration adding a config file to the .ebextensions folder.

**cors.config**

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/cors.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        location / {
             if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                #
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                #
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                #
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
             }
             if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
             }
             if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
             }
        }
```

but this is still not working for me.

Comment: did you add the conf file to `sites-enabled`?

Comment: @MikeTung I dont get what you mean? im quite new ti nginx

Comment: `/etc/nginx/sites-available` I believe is the path. You need to symlink your config file to that spot then reload nginx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set CORS headers in the response that goes out of your node/express application, you don't need to add anything to Nginx configuration.

Below is the configuration that worked for me, also running node.js on Beanstalk, and a cloudfront-hosted client application calling the API.

Modify as needed:

```
server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
  next()
})
```

Comment: This isn't entirely true. Elasic Beanstalk can be configured to serve static files from the proxy, without touching your application. In that case, only nginx (or apache) can be responsible for setting the CORS header.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me ...
I tried also cors npm package and Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"  ngix config via .ebextendsions and nothing happened. What is all you cors config to your node app ??

Comment: @mEnE cors npm package didn't work for me as well. If you serve your assets from nodejs application, you can use the solution above. If they are served via nginx then @carpiediem is right. You need something like 

```location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    expires max;
}```

Comment: I wanted to get API response from the api.my-domain URL and i solved this with Redirections config to my front end's web server.
Redirecting /api/* (https://my-domain.com/api/...)  to https://api.my-domain.com/...