# Call an Elastic Beanstalk Service from react native

Tags: react-native, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an Elastic Beanstalk service and can open it in my browser using ebopen.

However when I put the URL into my React Native code in order to make a fetch request to my service I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Network request failed
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (fetch.js:441)
at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (event-target.js:172)
at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (XMLHttpRequest.js:567)
at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (XMLHttpRequest.js:397)
at XMLHttpRequest.js:503
at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (EventEmitter.js:179)
at MessageQueue.__callFunction (MessageQueue.js:351)
at MessageQueue.js:116
at MessageQueue.__guardSafe (MessageQueue.js:314)
at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (MessageQueue.js:115)
```

My code looks like this:

```
class IntroScreen extends React.Component {
sendDataToBackend = async () => {
 fetch('https://<URL>').then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        console.log(response.statusText);
    }
    return response;
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log("ok");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
}

render() {

return (

    <View style={tutorialStyle.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        title=">"
        color="orange"
        height="40"
        onPress={() => this.sendDataToBackend()}
      />
    </View>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the react native code being served to the client from the same origin as the EB service?

If not, the error you are getting might be caused by the browser which often restricts this:  [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) (CORS).  To allow it, you have to change the header of your Elastic Beanstalk (EB) service.

Depending on your EB Operating System (Linux or Windows) and web server you set the header of your service app accordingly to allow cross origin calls.

[Here is an example](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=161108) of the way to set it for a containerized on Apache web server with Elastic Beanstalk.  [Here is a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48173717/enabling-cors-on-a-nginx-server-in-elasticbeanstalk) showing how to allow cors for an elastic beanstalk nginx install.

If you think cors is the cause of your error, you can try and find help or solution with more searching.  Or you could create a new question with your specific operating system and application setup information (which os, which app framework you used for your servce, elastic beanstalk specifics (load balanced or not, etc)) and we can try and guide you on the best way to fix cors.  The more detail you provide, the better we can help you.