# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check error in Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, cors

I have a website that is running on Apache server I get the following error when I try to open it:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://live-api.musanga.com/get_form_settings_via_domain' from
> origin 'https://live-customer-panel.musanga.com' has been blocked by
> CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Even though the response header shows `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` is present

I tried the following solutions adding this:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L,E=HTTP_ORIGIN:%{HTTP:ORIGIN}]]
```

to the httpd.conf file in the `<Directory "/var/www/html">` section and restarted apache but that did not work.

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the apache_mod "headers"?

```
sudo a2enmod headers 
sudo service apache2 restart
```

On centos you should add this line to your httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

Comment: I'm using Amazon Linux based on centos and headers module is enabled.

Comment: uhmm, In that case - could you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48721443/2498251 ?

Comment: I already have that in my backend node apps but that does not solve the problem.